# Get database name of table using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query which is selecting all of the column names based on some search criteria, however; I want to get the database name as well. How would I do this?

I have not been able to accomplish this with a join as of now. I am not sure what the relationship is between `sys.tables` and `sys.databases`. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
SELECT
    c.name  AS 'ColumnName',
    t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM 
    sys.columns c
JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE 
    c.name LIKE '%Broker%'
ORDER BY 
    TableName, ColumnName;
```

Thank you. I was able to accomplish my goal by using the below code with your guidance. For further clarity I added the schema.

```
SELECT      
    '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + ']' + '.' +  '[' + db_name() + ']' as "Database_Schema_Name",
    t.name AS 'Table_Name',
    c.name  AS 'Column_Name'
FROM        
    sys.columns c
JOIN
    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       
    c.name LIKE '%Broker%'
ORDER BY    
    Table_Name, Column_Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, the system tables are stored per database.  Hence, all is in one database, so you can just use [`dbname()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/db-name-transact-sql):

```
SELECT db_name() as DatabaseName, c.name AS ColumnName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c JOIN
     sys.tables t
     ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%Broker%'
ORDER BY TableName, ColumnName;
```

Note:  Because `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables are standard across databases, I prefer to get metadata information from those tables when available.  This also has the advantage that you only need `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, so no `JOIN` is (explicitly) necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
SELECT DB_NAME(3)AS [Database Name];
```